# Combining multiple rows in a single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have SQL Query like this in SSMS

```
select distinct (b.TransactionNumber),
(case when b.Amount > 0 then c.total else 0 end) as 'Total Sales',
(case when b.TenderID = 1 then b.Amount else 0 end) as 'Cash',
(case when b.TenderID = 20 then b.Amount else 0 end) as 'Gift Certificates'
from [Transaction] c
inner join TenderEntry b on c.TransactionNumber = b.TransactionNumber
```

but the output is(see image for reference)

[image: SQL Query Output]

This should be the expected output(see image for reference)

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: Output is such because of `distinct`. Whatever you expected is confusing. How do you want to aggregate - on which column? why/how second column should be aggregaed?

Comment: Please explain the rules for combining the rows.  How is `total sales` set to `0`?

Answer (score 1):

I would expect one row per transaction number, especially given your use of `select distinct`:

```
select t.TransactionNumber, te.total as total_sales,
       sum(case when t.TenderID = 1 then t.Amount else 0 end) as Cash,
       sum(case when t.TenderID = 20 then t.Amount else 0 end) as Gift_Certificates
from TenderEntry te join
     Transaction t
     on te.TransactionNumber = t.TransactionNumber
group by t.TransactionNumber, te.total;
```

This produces one row per transaction.

Note the changes to the query:

- The table aliases are *meaningful* (i.e. abbreviations of table names) rather than arbitrary letters.
- The column aliases do *not* use single quotes.  Only use single quotes for string and date constants.
- The column aliases have been simplified so they do not need to be escaped.

It occurs to me that you might want to "list" the cash and gifts in the two columns.  This would look like:

```
select TransactionNumber,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then total end) as total_sales,
       sum(case when tenderId = 1 then amount end) as cash,
       sum(case when tenderId = 20 then amount end) as Gift_Certificates
from (select t.TransactionNumber, te.total, t.amount, t.TenderID,
           row_number() over (partition by t.TransactionNumber, t.TenderId order by t.amount) as seqnum
      from TenderEntry te join
           Transaction t
           on te.TransactionNumber = t.TransactionNumber
      where tenderid in (1, 20)
     ) x
group by t.TransactionNumber, seqnum;
```

Comment: This is a more thorough answer than mine and fixes some bugs so I have upvoted it as such.

Comment: unfortunately, when there is a sum in the tenders(cash and gc), the amount was doubled depending on the number of items. like for example, I have 2 items, and the total sales is 500, when it comes to cash, it became 1000. Will there be anyway that I can still make it in one line?

Comment: @EimajMorales -  I am confused by the overall question and issue. It would be good if you edit your question. Please first describe how the data is stored when you do a transaction, (e.g., how many rows are created and what are in those rows?). Secondly, please describe how are these added together to get the output you would like.

Comment: @EimajMorales . . . You should probably ask a *new* question, providing sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer, but I put it here because I cannot fit it into comments well enough.

It is likely that you do not want the `DISTINCT` component in the select. SELECT DISTINCT find all unique *rows*. So if you have 3 rows which all have some differences, it will show all three. If, on the other hand, there were two rows the same (e.g., they paid for a $100 item with two $50 vouchers) it would just ignore one of them.

Instead, you probably need to become familiar with 'GROUP BY' which allows you to find totals etc across multiple rows.

For example (although not tested)

```
select 
    (b.TransactionNumber),
    (case when b.Amount > 0 then c.total else 0 end) as 'Total Sales',
    SUM(case when b.TenderID = 1 then b.Amount else 0 end) as 'Cash',
    SUM(case when b.TenderID = 20 then b.Amount else 0 end) as 'Gift Certificates'
from [Transaction] c
inner join TenderEntry b on c.TransactionNumber = b.TransactionNumber
GROUP BY (b.TransactionNumber, (case when b.Amount > 0 then c.total else 0 end))
```

In the above, I have removed the DISTINCT, added 'SUM' for the two transaction values (cash/certificates) and the GROUP BY across the TransactionNumber and Total sales (as that seems to be common across the transaction).

For the above data, what that would produce is 1 line of data for TransactionNumber = 1, with sales = 250 (as all the lines have that), and totals for cash and gift certificates (150 and 100 respectively if my maths is correct).

However, that is not your desired answer, - you want this transaction to go over two lines. Firstly, are you sure of that?

If you do, then we need another criteria by which to group them and you will need to specify that e.g., why does this transaction's report need to go over two lines rather than just one?

Other notes

- 'Transaction' is a special word within SQL Server. You are allowed to use it, but I would consider renaming the table.

Comment: I consider your suggestion to make the two lines as one. May I know on how can I work on this? Thank you

Comment: It's OK to have two lines if that's what you want - however we need to know the logic behind it (e.g., one line is for all negative transactions, and the other line is for all positive transactions. You would also need to confirm that no line could have both a negative and positive values for different fields). Re how you can work on this - I suggest reading about GROUP BY and try different things with the above. If you do want 2 rows per transaction, it will need a slightly more complex piece of code though (e.g., you would need to flag rows as positive or negative and then group by that too)

Comment: unfortunately, when there is a sum in the tenders(cash and gc), the amount was doubled depending on the number of items. like for example, I have 2 items, and the total sales is 500, when it comes to cash, it became 1000, Will there be anyway that I can still make it in one line?